# Is there an e-mail client which does not need to download mail?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, email

I would like to know if there is a mail client that just "reads" and sends emails without having to download them on the hard drive, due to limited disk space. The advantage over using a web mail interface is that the mail functions centralised for all accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell Thunderbird to use IMAP and not store attachments bigger than a given size and not keep too many emails on your computer.

[image]

I guess you cannot download *no* emails since they have to be displayed somehow, but this will minimize memory usage.

Comment: Very good this sound like a good approximation to what I intended. As far as you know, can this setting be applied also to POP accounts (Hotmail accounts in particular)?

Comment: Yes, you have basically the same options in POP accounts. You can choose to only download headers and not to download emails bigger then some kb. This would be what you want to do, I believe.